# Is there an 'override' option for mongoose insertMany() function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there an override option for mongoose `Model.insertMany()` function that would automatically override the document, based on one of its unique field?

For example, if for the following schema:

```js
{
  name: { type: String, unique: true },
  description: String,
}
```

Mongoose detect a duplicate error for the `name` key, is there an option to tell it *"It's ok override this line by the new line I'm trying to insert"*?

Comment: Did you searched for something like upsert Many ? Currently, mongoose does not offer it but there is this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@meanie/mongoose-upsert-many, maybe not exactly what you want because this also introduces a new dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `updateMany`, you can solve the problem

this code is trying to update the value but also insert when the target which is the originalName does not exist.

```js
User.updateMany({ name: originalName }, { $set: { name: newName }}, { upsert: true })
```

and this is the official mongodb document - [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#use-unique-indexes)